# Need help in creating MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

I am writing a trigger in a MySQL to conditionally create a new record in another table based on the value of field in newly added record in a table. Here is the script for the trigger (which should be self explanatory):

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_CREATE_INT_SRV_ROW
AFTER INSERT ON survey_details
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF(New.LossTo == 'Vehicle') THEN
    INSERT INTO survey_vehicle (RefNo) VALUES (New.RefNo);
 ELSE
    INSERT INTO survey_other (RefNo) VALUES (New.RefNo);
 END IF;
END;
```

While running the query, the error message displayed is:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'Vehicle') THEN
>       INSERT INTO interim_survey_vehicle (RefNo) VALUES (New.RefNo' at line 5

I am writing this kind of conditional trigger for the first time.

What is wrong with code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very straightforward.

There is no `==` operator.

Please change

```
IF(New.LossTo == 'Vehicle') THEN
```

to

```
IF(New.LossTo = 'Vehicle') THEN
```

## UPDATE 2018-02-26 11:04 EST

You need to change the delimiter before and after the trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS TRG_CREATE_INT_SRV_ROW $$
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_CREATE_INT_SRV_ROW
 AFTER INSERT ON survey_details
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF(New.LossTo = 'Vehicle') THEN
    INSERT INTO survey_vehicle (RefNo) VALUES (New.RefNo);
 ELSE
    INSERT INTO survey_other (RefNo) VALUES (New.RefNo);
 END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Please see my old post [Unique combination key MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22085/unique-combination-key-mysql/22119#22119) for an example